# TFS silently fixes .sln files - Is there a way to stop it?

Tags: .net, tfs

Imagine the following scenario:

> `Solution1.sln` contains projects `A`, `B` and `C`. (.NET 4.0, C#)
>
> `Solution2.sln` contains projects `A`, `B` and `D`. (.NET 4.0, C#)

A developer working in `Solution2.sln` adds a reference to `D` in `B`. Obviously, `Solution1.sln` doesn't compile anymore because it doesn't contain `D` (tested, just to make sure, with VS2010, VS2013 and standalone MSBuild).

The "issue" is that the nightly build running `Solution1.sln` works fine, surprisingly. When I look at the `.sln` file on my build server I see that it was modified to add the missing project.

This looks like a nice feature at first, but I'd rather be aware that a solution is broken than having builds that magically work.

Is there a way to turn this feature off in TFS2013? I'm *quite* positive that this doesn't happen in TFS2010, but I can't say for TFS2012.

Comment: It shouldn't do that. Are you sure the sln file gets modified on the build box? Can you open the sln file on the server to check where the reference points to?

Comment: @AdarshShah The "date modified" of the .sln is a minute later than all the other files which date back to the "Get Workspace" part of the build workflow. Perhaps I should have mentioned that the missing project *is* in the workspace, simply not in the solution. The `.sln` file on the build server contains a reference to the right project.

Comment: Is it a project reference or an assembly reference?

Comment: It's a project sitting the the same directory as the other ones and the solution. I suppose it can find the right project using its GUID.

Comment: When you say "A developer working in Solution2.sln adds a reference to D in B". Is that a project reference or an assembly reference?

Comment: Project references everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is just a set of projects, nothing more.

When MSBuild works on a solution, it computes the build order analyzing project and binary references -- this process is identical in Visual Studio and in Team Build (i.e. TFS). For project references it determines from build outputs if a project should rebuild. As long as MSBuild is able to resolve references on the file system, everything is fine.

You will see the same behavior in Visual Studio: you just get a warning, but build succeeds.

Team Build use a single directory for all build outputs, so the order you use to build the solutions can influence binary reference too.

Comment: Well as I mentioned in the question, the build fails in VS and with standalone MSBuild. I don't get any warning... Are there any settings to change to get the behavior you mentioned?

Comment: I tested with VS 2013.1, so maybe MSBuild 12 has a different behavior, but I don't think so.
Maybe there is something that you are missing in your configuration that is causing you problems.